# What would be the best way to run a loop within a print statement that is extracting data from a list in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to extract data from a csv file, this is the shortened version of one of the columns of data

```
import csv

with open('Movie2.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    counter = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
        counter +=1
        print('Movie m%d' % counter, "= new Movie();", '\n',
                 'm'+str(counter)+'.Genres.Add(db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "' % line[2]+'"));', '\n')
```

"line[2]" is usually multiple genres and may look like this "Horror, Thriller, Drama". My goal is for this particular code the end result should looke like:

```
Movie m1 = new Movie();
m1.Genres.Add (db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "Horror"));
m1.Genres.Add (db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "Thriller"));
m1.Genres.Add (db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "Drama"));
```

Comment: You can use `for index, line in enumerate(csv_reader):`. That will improve your code and you will not need any `counter`.

Answer (score 1):

You call `print` multiple times from within a loop, not the other way around.

```
for counter, line in enumerate(csv_reader, start=1):
    var = 'm%d' % (counter,)
    genres = line[2].split(", ")
    print('Movie %s = new Movie()' % (var,))
    for genre in genres:
        print('%s.Genres.Add (db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "%s"))' % (var, genre))
```

The alternative of joining a list of lines with `\n'` and calling `print` once is arguably less readable:

```
for counter, line in enumerate(csv_reader, start=1):
    var = 'm%d' % (counter,)
    genres = line[2].split(", ")
    code_lines = ['Movie %s = new Movie();' % (var,)]
    code_lines.extend('%s.Genres.Add (db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GenreName == "%s"))' % (var, genre) for genre in genres)
    print("\n".join(code_lines))
```

although not so much that I would push one over the other.